# Google API: Gmail Service Push Notification (Watch) - User not authorized to perform this action

Tags: c#, push-notification, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to call watch() on a mailbox. I set up a service Iam account, and created a topic and suscription.  I gave my service account full(owner) rights to my topic and subscription. But when calling execute on watch(), I get the error:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Error sending test message to Cloud PubSub projects/projectid/topics/topicname : User not authorized to perform this action. [403] Errors [ Message[Error sending test message to Cloud PubSub projects/projectid/topics/topicname : User not authorized to perform this action.] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global] ]
```

Here is the code I use to set up my  service:

```
 credential = new X509Certificate2("file.p12"), "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = applicationame,
        });


WatchRequest body = new WatchRequest()
    {
        TopicName = "projects/projectid/topics/topicname",
        LabelIds = new[] {"INBOX"}
string userId = "me";
UsersResource.WatchRequest watchRequest = service.Users.Watch(body, userId);
WatchResponse test = watchRequest.Execute();
```

My service account has access to all the following scopes:

```
https://mail.google.com/
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata
```

Am I missing something here?

EDIT

Added the following scope, but still not success: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub`

EDIT
Also added the following with no success: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`

Comment: I don't have access to a google domains account so I cant test it.  However I have seen the issue before.    It stems back to the service accounts permission it doesn't have permission to that user.

Comment: @DaImTo which user are you referring to? So far, I have given the service account email permission to the topic. Do you mean the service account email need some rights to the actual gmail account being watched, even though the service account was created by the gmail account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not give the service account that gmail uses to publish updates to Pub/Sub permission to publish to the topic (TopicName):  `serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com`  I gave this account permission in the console.

Comment: +1 You saved my day .. for the past two days i ran into same issue.. your info was helped me and got it. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out!!. this was a bit annoying to find.  Docs for reference - https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#grant_publish_rights_on_your_topic

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that a service account is not you.  A service account is a dummy user which has a google drive account a google calendar account and probably a bunch more.   However it does **not** have a gmail account.

Service accounts are preauthorized. You need to grant the service account access to read the users email.

userId's needs to be the id of the user whos emails you wish to access.  'Me' wont work because a serveries account doesn't  have a gmail account it has no emails to read.

Comment: I have granted the service account access by giving the cientId the appropriate scopes. Also, I tried changing "me" to the Gmail username but the error persists.

Comment: how do you grant the service account access to read a user's email?

Comment: Try the users email address. I don't have access to a domain account anymore so can't guide you on how to grant it access

Answer (score 0):

Just need the scopes:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub

In the Cloud Pub/Sub Developer Console you need to grant publish privileges to serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!

Comment: In fact, the scope pubsub is not even necessary. Any single one of these is enough: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users/watch#authorization-scopes