# Gmail API watch request not working properly

Tags: gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

`There are many post on this same topic but still there is no exact solution to solve this issue.`

even in the google API below link, there is a option to test the API 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch

This API throws a error like `Invalid Topic Name does not match` but I have created the topic in the pub sub and I have published the message on it, that topic works fine but then also I am receiving below error. I am receiving 400 error

```
{ "error": {"errors": [{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "invalidArgument",
"message": "Invalid topicName does not match projects/google.com:apisexplorerconsole/topics/*"   }  ],"code": 400,"message":"Invalid topicName does not match projects/google.com:apisexplorerconsole/topics/*" }}
```

I have tried to call this API in client side, like below

```
gapi.client.gmail.users.watch({
    'userId': 'me',
     "topicName": "projects/fast-metric-178608/topics/Test" 
  }).then(function (response) { 
        console.log(response) 
  });
```

Below is output , i am receiving 403 error

```
{ "error": { "errors": [{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "forbidden",
"message": "Error sending test message to Cloud PubSub projects/fast-metric-178608/topics/Test : User not authorized to perform this action."}  ],"code": 403,  "message": "Error sending test message to Cloud PubSub projects/fast-metric-178608/topics/Test : User not authorized to perform this action." }}
```

Comment: You are getting 400 error  because you are using API explorer. As stated in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30990958/5995040), do not use API explorer to test it as suggested in other post.You can use Cloud Pub/SUb calls as it says in the guide ([using your own service-account client](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)).

Comment: Lastly, check if you have properly gave your service account permission to post in Pub/Sub as stated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43330485/5995040) and [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-pubsub-discuss/PjWGWbxtcQ4).

Comment: Thanks for reply , i have created service account and i am passing clientId  as param for authentication method                                                               var clientId = '89989545454-xyz.apps.googleusercontent.com';  function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({
          client_id: clientId,
          scope: scopes,
          immediate: true
        }, handleAuthResult);
      }

Answer (score 0):

https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudpubsub/topicList

select your topic and
set your topic PERMISSIONS allUser and Select a role Pub/Sub Admin